# Put Fragments inside another Fragment which contains tabs?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `BottomNavigationView` which contains Fragments and in one of those Fragments I put tabs and in those tabs I want to put Fragments, but I do not know how to do this is what I have right now in the interface:

This the code where I have tabs in the snippet and marked the error
What do I have to add or change to make it work?

**My fragment code:**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private Toolbar supportActionBar;

public HomeFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_whatshot_black_24dp));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_person_black_24dp));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_phone_black_24dp));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);


    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);


    **Here it marks an error that I have wrong**

    PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            int position = tab.getPosition();
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    }); 

    return view;
   }


public void setSupportActionBar(Toolbar supportActionBar) {
    this.supportActionBar = supportActionBar;
   }

   }
```

The problem is in this line

```
  PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
```

**PagerAdapter code:**

```
 public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private int numberTabs;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numberTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.numberTabs=numberTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position){

        case 0:
            return new FragmentNovedades();
        case 1:
            return new FragmentCuenta();
        case 2:
            return new FragmentContacto();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return numberTabs;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getSupportFragmentManager()` is used when you want to have a fragment inside the activity. But in your case you are using tablayout inside Fragment. So all fragments inside tablayout are manipulated with `getChildFragmentManager()` method. You can read more about `getChildFragmentManager()` method [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

Comment: Thank you I did not know I could take this method I will put it into operation and I will see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the child FragmentManager for Fragments within Fragments.

If you want the support library, you need to import the correct Fragment class

Comment: How could I do it? I'm new to programming and I don't know what I'd have to call I do not know if he could help me.

Comment: the way you replace the fragment inside activity with getSupportFragmentManager() , the same way you can replace fragment inside the fragment with getChildFragmentManager() and every thing will work smoothly. I know its hard for the begineers but you can do it if you take some time on it

Comment: @CarlosMario If you search "ChildFragmentManager" in the documentation, it'll give you the info seek.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: @RamMandal Thanks for the reply. I'll see how that method works.

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for the link.